# Regex in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I need some help on a problem.

In fact I search to check for an image type by the hexadecimal code.

```
string JpgHex = "FF-D8-FF-E0-xx-xx-4A-46-49-46-00";
```

Then I have a condition on

```
string.StartsWith(pngHex).
```

The problem is that the "x" characters presents in my "JpgHex" string can be whatever I want.

I think I need a regex to check that but I don't know how!!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you more clearly define `whatever I want` ? Alphabets? Numbers? Whitespaces?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html Read the `Character Classes or Character Sets` section. Also check `The Dot Matches (Almost) Any Character`

Comment: It's Hexadecimal characters!

Comment: The question you should be asking is why are you trying to search for an image type using the hexadecimal code.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said, I'd need a better idea of what pattern you need to match.

Here are some examples:

```
Regex rgx = 
       new Regex(@"^FF-D8-FF-E0-[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-4A-46-49-46-00$");
rgx.IsMatch(pngHex); // is match will return a bool.
```

I use `[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}` to denote two instances of a character, caps or small or a number. So the above regex would match :

```
FF-D8-FF-E0-aa-zZ-4A-46-49-46-00
FF-D8-FF-E0-11-22-4A-46-49-46-00
.. etc
```

1. Based on your need change the regex accordingly so for capitals and numbers **only** you change to `[A-Z0-9]`. The `{2}` denotes two occurrences.
2. The `^` denotes the string should start with `FF` and `$` means the string should end with `00`.

Lets say you wanted to only match **two** numbers, so you would use `\d{2}`, the whole thing would look like this:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^FF-D8-FF-E0-\d{2}-\d{2}-4A-46-49-46-00$");
rgx.IsMatch(pngHex);
```

How do I know of these magical characters? Simple, there are docs everywhere. See this MSDN page for some basic [regex patterns.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4.aspx) This page shows some [quantifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx), those are things like *match one or more* or *match only one*.

[Cheat-sheets also come in handy](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear what exactly you want to do, but the dot '.' character represents any character in Regex.

So the regex "^FF-D8-FF-E0-..-..-4A-46-49-46-00" will probably do the trick. '^' = Start of input.

If you want to allow only hex chars you can use "^FF-D8-FF-E0-[0-9A-F]{2}-[0-9A-F]{2}-4A-46-49-46-00".

Answer (score 0):

A regex would help you; you can use the following tool to help you test and learn: -

http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

*I recommend you have a play because then you'll learn!*

To simply match **any** character in place of the x, the following should work: -

"^FF-D8-FF-E0-..-..-4A-46-49-46-00$"

In C#, it would be something like this: -

```
var test = "FF-D8-FF-E0-AB-CD-4A-46-49-46-00";

var foo = new Regex("^FF-D8-FF-E0-..-..-4A-46-49-46-00$");

if (foo.IsMatch(test))
{
  // Do magic
}
```

You will need to read up on regular expressions to understand some of the characters that may not look familiar, i.e. ^ and $. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: I like that but the var "test" has to start with foo, "test" can be longer than foo!

Comment: If test is longer than what you are matching, you have a couple of options; i.e. remove the, '$'. You should probably not remove the '^' as you may run into the unfortunate scenario where your file 'coincidentally' contains the initial search string